# Spring MVC: override default MessageSource object

Tags: java, spring-mvc, internationalization

Due to [this article](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-how-to-access-messagesource-in-bean-messagesourceaware/) and documentation:

> During Spring container initialization, if any class which implements
>   the MessageSourceAware interface, Spring will automatically inject the
>   MessageSource into the class via setMessageSource(MessageSource
>   messageSource) setter method.

but the access methods of that object are not so usefull, so I wanted to override that interface and add some more usefull methods:

```
public class MessageSourceEx implements org.springframework.context.MessageSource {

    /**
     * 
     */
    @Override
    public String getMessage(MessageSourceResolvable source, Locale locale)
            throws NoSuchMessageException {
        return this.getMessage(source, locale);
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    @Override
    public String getMessage(String key, Object[] params, Locale locale)
            throws NoSuchMessageException {
        return this.getMessage(key, params, locale);
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    @Override
    public String getMessage(String key, Object[] params, String locale, Locale locale2) {
        return this.getMessage(key, params, locale, locale2);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param locale Locale
     * @param key Key
     * @param params Parameters
     * @return
     */
    public String getMessage(Locale locale, String key, Object... params) {
        return this.getMessage(key, new Object[] {params}, locale);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param locale Locale
     * @param key Key
     * @return
     */
    public String getMessage(Locale locale, String key) {
        return this.getMessage(key, null, locale);
    }
}
```

But the problem is that `MessageSourceAware` interface requires setter method exactly for MessageSource and can't get my overriden class as a parameter..  From the other side I can't cast MessageSource to my object - it fails with exception..

Is it possible to implement such thing?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general don't understand your issue.
From `MessageSourceAware` JavaDocs:

> Interface to be implemented by any object that wishes to be notified
>     of the MessageSource (typically the ApplicationContext) that it runs in.
>
> Note that the MessageSource can usually also be passed on as bean
>     reference (to arbitrary bean properties or constructor arguments), because
>     it is defined as bean with name "messageSource" in the application context.

So, just configure your implementation as **messageSource** bean:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="com.my.proj.FooMessageSource"/>
```

and your services should just implement `MessageSourceAware`.
And, of course, in those classes you can cast `MessageSource` to your implementation, if needed.

Documentation is here: [Internationalization using MessageSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-messagesource)

Comment: `just configure your implementation as messageSource bean` - what do you mean?